# Can I install two Ubuntu versions on the same machine?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, ubuntu-10.10

I have Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit already installed on my machine. I am using MongoDB and it does not work properly with 32 bit machine.

So I want to install 64 bit Ubuntu 10.10 on my system on another partition (So that I can have both 32 bit and 64 bit versions).

Is it okay to install both 32 bit and 64 bit. I mean will it give any problem? and on which partition I should install 64 bit version ..my partitions are as follows

```
  Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda1              37G   11G   25G  30% /
  none                  1.4G  260K  1.4G   1% /dev
  none                  1.4G  776K  1.4G   1% /dev/shm
  none                  1.4G  244K  1.4G   1% /var/run
  none                  1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /var/lock
  /dev/sda6             129G   73G   50G  60% /home
  /dev/sda7             127G   76G   45G  64% /vol
```

Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can.
And, since you have a separately /home partition, you can use the same /home on your 2 different system.

> /dev/sda7             127G   76G   45G  64% /vol

I suggest you to use **GParted** to resize the /vol partition (backup your important data before you resize the partition!), then create a new partition and install the 64 bit Ubuntu on it.